# Is there a way to consume files only from sub directories using camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

For example, I have a camel route that looks like this:

```
from("file:data/input").to("file:output");
```

And the "input" folder also has two subfolders, for example "folder1" and "folder2".

**Is there a possibility to consume files only from the subfolders, without consuming from "input" ?**

I tried using two camel routes for each subfolder. But lets say that with time, the number of subfolders will increase to an unmanagable number. I don't want to create a camel route for each subfolder. I want to create a single camel route that can consume from each subfolder, but not from the root folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah set `recursive=true`, and then set the `minDepth=2` (see the docs):
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/file-component.adoc